# How to carry script over to multiple google sheet tabs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to have 3 google sheets that are all sorted according to column 3 across all of the rows. I have been able to do that on sheet 1 but I want sheet 2 and 3 to be sorted according to column 3 as well. All of the sheets have =importrange included so column 3 is exactly the same on each of the 3 sheets. I'm very new at this and have so far been unable to get them to communicate and have tried multiple different ways including:

```
    var totalSheets =sheets.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalSheets; i++)
```

This is my original script that works for Sheet 1 only:

```
  function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 3;
  var tableRange = "A3:Z999";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. IMHO the que questions needs more focus and you should add more details like if are getting and error message and in such cased include the textual error message. By the other hand, are you aware of how simple triggers works in Google Apps Script / Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

If column C is the result of importrange, you will not be able to sort by script. Instead use query with importange as following:

```
=query(importrange(___________)," select * order by Col3 asc ",1)
```